# How to convert this SQL query to LINQ or Lambda expression in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, lambda

I have the following simple table:

```html
table : Inventory
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   Id  | ProductId |   cost    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |   1       |     10    |
|   2   |   2       |     55    |
|   3   |   1       |     42    |
|   4   |   3       |     102   |
|   5   |   2       |     110   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have the following SQL query:

```html
SELECT T.Id
FROM Inventory AS T INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT ProductId
                               FROM Inventory
                               GROUP BY ProductId
                               HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS S ON T.ProductId = S.ProductId
```

This works to give me all of the Ids where a duplicate ProductId exists. Using the above table, this query would return Ids { 1,2,3,5 }, which is exactly what I want.

I tried converting this into a Lambda expression, but it continually fails with the join. Can anyone get me started and point me in the right direction to write this expression?

This is what I have tried:

```cs
var q = inventory.Join( inventory.GroupBy( o => o.ProductId ).Where( o => o.Count( ) > 1 ), g => g.ProductId, gb => gb.Key, ( g, gb ) => g.Id ).ToList( );
```

Comment: can you show us the lambda you tried?

Comment: LINQ is *not* a SQL replacement. It's a query language used on top of ORMs. ORMs in turn are *not* meant for reporting queries like this one. Which ORM are you using anyway?

Comment: Finding duplicates in T-SQL is far easier using `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID)` or `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ..)`

Comment: Don't know why you need both a GroupBy and Join.  You can use just the GroupBy.

Comment: You're right. The join was the issue. I was mistakenly attempting to literally adapt T-SQL to LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use somthing like this:

```
 var result = Inventory
   .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
   .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
   .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
   .Select(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: You don't need that `ToList` inside of the `SelectMany`.

Comment: Thanks @Mehrdad Dowlatabadi. You saved me a headache.

Comment: @juharr Right, thank you for the point.  np,glad i could help.